# Is there a way to upload a file in digital ocean object storage using php curl

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, cloud-object-storage

I want to upload a file to digital ocean spaces. This suppose to be S3 compatible.

However I do not want to use their library, I want standalone file.

Laste days, I try several examples, including one from their website, but nothing worked.

I have S3 uploader binary and it works fine, also rclone works OK, so my credentials are fine.

Note I do not looking for pre-signed URL.

Example in shell + curl will be also sufficient because I will be able to rewrite to php.

Comment: Did you check this digital ocean spaces API - https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/#hello-world-program?

Comment: Yes but I do not see any error in most of the scripts I checked.

Comment: You could use the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/), pointing it at Digital Ocean.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot help you if you simply say "nothing worked". If you want us to assist you, then please show the code you used and the _exact_ error message.

Answer (score -2):

I finally was able to fix errors from DigitalOcean own script.

Here is **working** curl:

```
space="nmmm-test"
REGION="ams3"
STORAGETYPE="STANDARD" # Storage type, can be STANDARD, REDUCED_REDUNDANCY, etc.
KEY="xxxx"
SECRET="xxxxxx"

path="/home/nmmm/"
file="despicable-me-2-minions_a-G-10438535-0.jpg"
space_path="/"
date=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
acl="x-amz-acl:public-read" # private or public-read.
content_type="image/jpeg"
storage_type="x-amz-storage-class:${STORAGETYPE}"

string="PUT\n\n$content_type\n$date\n$acl\n$storage_type\n/$space$space_path$file"
signature=$(echo -en "${string}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${SECRET}" -binary | base64)
curl -v -s -X PUT -T "$path/$file" \
-H "Host: $space.${REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com" \
-H "Date: $date" \
-H "Content-Type: $content_type" \
-H "$storage_type" \
-H "$acl" \
-H "Authorization: AWS ${KEY}:$signature" \
"https://$space.${REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com$space_path$file"
```

The file is based on DigitalOcean example from here:
https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/#hello-world-program

After that I did working PHP class

```
<?php

class S3Uploader{
    private $s3_host;   // ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com
    private $s3_key;
    private $s3_secret;
    private $s3_bucket;

    private $s3_storage_class;
    private $s3_acl;

    const ACL_PRIVATE   = "private";
    const ACL_PUBLIC    = "public-read";

    const SC_STANDARD   = "STANDARD";

    const DEBUG     = false;

    function __construct($s3_host, $s3_key, $s3_secret, $s3_bucket){
        $this->s3_host      = $s3_bucket . "." . $s3_host;
        $this->s3_key       = $s3_key;
        $this->s3_secret    = $s3_secret;
        $this->s3_bucket    = $s3_bucket;

        $this->s3_storage_class = self::SC_STANDARD;
        $this->s3_acl       = self::ACL_PUBLIC;
    }

    function setStorageClass($s3_storage_class){
        // STANDARD, REDUCED_REDUNDANCY, etc.
        $this->s3_storage_class = $s3_storage_class;
    }

    function setAcl($acl){
        // "private" or "public-read"
        $this->s3_acl       = $acl;
    }

    function setAclBool($acl){
        if ($acl)
            return setAcl(self::ACL_PUBLIC);
        else
            return setAcl(self::ACL_PRIVATE);
    }

    private static function date(){
        return strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %T %z");
    }

    function uploadFile($src_file, $dst_file, $content_type){
        $date       = $this->date();

        // space after : is ommited intentionally!!!
        $acl        = "x-amz-acl:"          . $this->s3_acl;
        $storage_class  = "x-amz-storage-class:"    . $this->s3_storage_class;

        $string     =   "PUT\n"         .
                    "\n"                .
                    "$content_type\n"   .
                    "$date\n"           .
                    "$acl\n"            .
                    "$storage_class\n"  .
                    "/" . $this->s3_bucket . $dst_file
        ;

        $signature = base64_encode(
                    hash_hmac("sha1", $string, $this->s3_secret, true)
        );

        $curl_headers = [
            "Host:"         . $this->s3_host            ,
            "Date:"         . $date                     ,
            "Content-Type:"     . $content_type         ,
            $acl                                        ,
            $storage_class                              ,
            "Authorization:"    . "AWS " . $this->s3_key . ":" . $signature
        ];

        $curl_url = "https://" . $this->s3_host . $dst_file;

        $file_contents  = file_get_contents($src_file);

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,             $curl_url       );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,   "PUT"           );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,      $file_contents  );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,      $curl_headers   );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  true            );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true            );

        if (self::DEBUG){
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,          true            );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,         true            );
        }

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        if ($result === false) {
                @curl_close($curl);

            // int is more readable in print_r

            return [
                "ok"        => 0                        ,
                "http_code" => 0                        ,
                "curl_error"    => curl_errno($curl)    ,
                "message"   => curl_error($curl)
            ];
        }else{
            $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                @curl_close($curl);

            // int is more readable in print_r

            return [
                "ok"        => $code == 200 ? 1 : 0         ,
                "http_code" => $code                        ,
                "curl_error"    => curl_errno($curl)        ,
                "message"   => $code == 200 ? "" : $result
            ];
        }
    }
};

$s3 = new S3Uploader("ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "nmmm-test");

$r = $s3->uploadFile("/home/nmmm/despicable-me-2-minions_a-G-10438535-0.jpg", "/minion.jpg", "image/jpeg");

print_r($r);
```

You can find two files here:

https://github.com/nmmmnu/S3Upload

Comment: Can you add some info about why the **DigitalOcean** scripts are _not working_ ? (and which errors they produced, so more people might be able to find this)

Comment: https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/#hello-world-program - shell curl example does not "compile". Also is unnecessary complex. My shell file is based on it, but it took me 40 min to make it work.

Comment: There is no need to "compile" a shell curl example.

Comment: it is a figure of speech that is why in quotes